After creating a Custom Tokenizer using HF Tokenizers library, how to create a model that fits the Tokenizer?
I followed this tutorial to create a custom Tokenizer based on SentencePieceBPE class, with a custom pre-tokenizer class. The newly trained Tokenizer was successfully trained with a dataset and saved on the HuggingFace platform.
I can load my custom Tokenizer class without a problem, using code like this:
tokenizer = MyCustomTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('myusername/mytokenizer')

Specifically, let's take a pre-trained model as an example. Originally, my sequence-to-sequence pipeline uses a pre-trained model named fnlp/bart-base-chinese as tokenizer and model.
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BertTokenizer

checkpoint = 'fnlp/bart-base-chinese'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(checkpoint, output_attentions = True, output_hidden_states = True)

If I change the tokenizer to my custom Tokenizer class, the model has to modify/re-train as well.
checkpoint = 'fnlp/bart-base-chinese'
tokenizer = MyCustomTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('myusername/mytokenizer')
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(checkpoint, output_attentions = True, output_hidden_states = True) # this one has to change?!

In theory, a tokenizer will tokenize a corpus with a set of Token IDs. The model that uses the tokenizer understands this set of Token IDs. If I change the tokenizer to my custom one, the model has to change / re-train as well.
Is my concept correct? If yes, how should I re-build the model to make it "compatible" with my custom Tokenizer?
Thanks in advance.

Indeed, your understanding is correct. When switching the tokenizer in a pre-trained model, it's necessary to adjust the model as well to ensure compatibility between the tokenizer and the model's architecture. Here's an approach to using your model:
Utilize MyCustomTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('myusername/mytokenizer') to load your custom tokenizer, ensuring seamless integration. You can find detailed documentation on loading custom tokenizers in the Hugging Face Transformers documentation.
Take the time to examine the properties and methods of your custom tokenizer to understand its functionality thoroughly. The Hugging Face documentation provides comprehensive details on tokenizer properties and methods, allowing you to gain a deeper understanding of your custom tokenizer's capabilities.
Adjust the model inputs to align with the outputs of your custom tokenizer. This may entail reshaping inputs, handling token IDs, attention masks, etc. Resources on model input modification can be found in the Hugging Face Transformers documentation.
Depending on the extent of changes made to the tokenizer or model inputs, re-training or fine-tuning the model may be necessary for optimal performance on your specific task or dataset. Tutorials and guides on model re-training and fine-tuning are available in the Hugging Face community forum.
Here's some code I've experimented with
from transformers import BartForConditionalGeneration

# Load the custom tokenizer
tokenizer = MyCustomTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('myusername/mytokenizer')

# Tokenize text using the custom tokenizer
inputs = tokenizer("Your input text goes here", return_tensors="pt")

# Load the pre-trained BART model
model_checkpoint = 'fnlp/bart-base-chinese'
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, output_attentions=True, output_hidden_states=True)

# Adapt model inputs to match the outputs of the custom tokenizer
input_ids = inputs["input_ids"]
attention_mask = inputs["attention_mask"]

# Example forward pass
outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

# Continue with your model training or evaluation process...

Ensure careful alignment between the tokenizer and model to maintain compatibility. Re-training or fine-tuning may be necessary based on the modifications made. I hope I was able to steer you into the right path, please leave feedback, as it was a while since I've tackled a question like this.

Thanks for the answer. I use a similar approach, but my overridden forward pass encountered quite a lot of problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78266597/typeerror-forward-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-token-type-ids

also, can you tell me how to continue with the training process? originally I used Seq2SeqTrainer to train my model.

To continue training, reload your pre trained model with BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_path), specify new training parameters using Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, and create a Seq2SeqTrainer instance with your model and training settings. Then resume training with trainer.train(), making necessary adjustments and debugging as needed.

Lots of errors occurred during training, such as: TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder_outputs'
