TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token_type_ids'
Using the HuggingFace Transformers framework, I encountered a problem when I used a custom forward() function in a custom class to fine-tune a pre-trained model to match my custom Tokenizer, but a strange error occurred:

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token_type_ids'

Here is the code:
class MyModel(BartForConditionalGeneration):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, decoder_input_ids=None, decoder_attention_mask=None, head_mask=None):
        return super().forward(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
            decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
            head_mask=head_mask,
        )

# load the model with custom tokenizer
model = MyModel(BartConfig.from_pretrained(checkpoint)).half().cuda()
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
model.config.vocab_size = len(tokenizer)
model.config.use_cache = False

The whole piece of code does not have token_type_ids at all.
The trackback is as follows:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:2

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1645, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1640     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1642 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1643     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1644 )
-> 1645 return inner_training_loop(
   1646     args=args,
   1647     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1648     trial=trial,
   1649     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1650 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1938, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1935     self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state, self.control)
   1937 with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
-> 1938     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1940 if (
   1941     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   1942     and not is_torch_tpu_available()
   1943     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   1944 ):
   1945     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   1946     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2759, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2756     return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)
   2758 with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2759     loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2761 if self.args.n_gpu > 1:
   2762     loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2784, in Trainer.compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2782 else:
   2783     labels = None
-> 2784 outputs = model(**inputs)
   2785 # Save past state if it exists
   2786 # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
   2787 if self.args.past_index >= 0:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token_type_ids'

My question is: How can I resolve this problem?
UPDATE
I researched on the Internet, and found out that I can add the following attribute to the tokenizer loading:
tokenizer = MyTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(tokenizer_repo, return_token_type_ids="token_type_ids")

OR
tokenizer = MyTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(tokenizer_repo, return_token_type_ids=True)

but after applying this code, the error persists.
Versions: (not all the latest versions due to version conflict with other libraries)

accelerate 0.28.2
transformers 4.36.2
tokenizers 0.15.2
spacy-transformers 1.3.4


UPDATE 2
After removing token_type_ids in the DatasetDict, the training seems to be working, but in evaluating after the first 5000 steps, the process stops with another error:

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder_outputs'

which the encoder_outputs never appears in any codes. I wonder if the BartForConditionalGeneration is not suitable for the base class of the fine-tuning model. In the source code of BartForConditionalGeneration, I found the following related codes: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py#L999
I am unsure what I should do next now.
